# SetThreadAffinityMask of pooled thread

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, threadpool

I am wondering whether it is possible to set the processor affinity of a thread obtained from a thread pool. More specifically the thread is obtained through the use of TimerQueue API which I use to implement periodic tasks.

As a sidenote: I found TimerQueues the easiest way to implement periodic tasks but since these are usually longliving tasks might it be more appropriate to use dedicated threads for this purpose? Furthermore it is anticipated that synchronization primites such as semapores and mutexes need to be used to synchronize the various periodic tasks. Are the pooled threads suitable for these?

Thanks!

EDIT1: As Leo has pointed out the above question is actually two only loosely related ones. The first one is related to processor affinity of pooled threads. The second question is related to whether pooled threads obtained from the TimerQueue API are behaving just like manually created threads when it comes to synchronization objects. I will move this second question the a seperate topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do this, make sure you return things to how they were every time you release a thread back to the pool. Since you don't own those threads and other code which uses them may have other requirements/assumptions.

**Are you sure you actually need to do this, though?** It's very, very rare to need to set processor affinity. (I don't think I've ever needed to do it in anything I've written.)

**Thread affinity can mean two quite different things.** (Thanks to bk1e's comment to my original answer for pointing this out. I hadn't realised myself.)

1. What I would call **processor affinity**: Where a thread needs to be run consistently on a the same processor. This is what SetThreadAffinityMask deals with and it's very rare for code to care about it. (Usually it's due to very low-level issues like CPU caching in high performance code. Usually the OS will do its best to keep threads on the same CPU and it's usually counterproductive to force it to do otherwise.)
2. What I would call **thread affinity**: Where objects use thread-local storage (or some other state tied to the thread they're accessed from) and will go wrong if a sequence of actions is not done on the same thread.

**From your question it sounds like you may be confusing #1 with #2.** The thread itself will not change *while your callback is running*. While a thread is running it may jump between CPUs but that is normal and not something you have to worry about (except in very special cases).

Mutexes, semaphores, etc. do not care if a thread jumps between CPUs.

If your callback is executed by the thread pool multiple times, there is (depending on how the pool is used) usually no guarantee that the same thread will be used each time. i.e. Your callback may jump between threads, but not while it is in the middle of running; it may only change threads each time it runs again.

Some synchronization objects *will* care if your callback code runs on one thread and then, still thinking it holding locks on those objects, runs again on a different thread. (The first thread will still hold the locks, not the second one, although it depends which kind of synchronization object you use. Some don't care.) That isn't a #1, though; that's #2, and not something you'd use SetThreadAffinityMask to deal with.

As an example, Mutexes (CreateMutex) are owned by a thread. If you acquire a mutex on Thread A then any other thread which tries to acquire the mutex will block until you release the mutex on Thread A. (It is also an error for a thread to release a mutex it does not own.) So if your callback acquired a mutex, then exited, then ran again on another thread and released the mutex from there, it would be wrong.

On the other hand, an Event (CreateEvent) does not care which threads create, signal or destroy it. You can signal an event on one thread and then reset it on another and that's fine (normal, in fact).

It'd also be rare to hold a synchronization object between two separate runs of your callback (that would invite deadlocks, although there are certainly situations where you could legitimately want/do such a thing). However, if you created (for example) an apartment-threaded COM object then that would be something you would want to only access from one specific thread.

Comment: Microsoft's documentation also uses "thread affinity" to refer to the processor affinity of a specific thread: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684251%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: @bk1e, I stand corrected. That's confusing, then. :) By the sound of it I think the OP is worried about objects which need to be used consistently from a single thread rather than threads which need to be run consistently on a single CPU. I'll clarify my answer. Thanks!

Comment: "Some synchronization objects will care [...] Some don't care." could you give an example of a syncronization object that DOES care?

Comment: @Arne, Sure, I added a couple of examples for you.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't. You're only supposed to use that thread for the job at hand, on the processor it's running on at that point. Apart from the obvious inefficiency, the threadpool might destroy every thread as soon as you're done, and create a new one for your next job. The affinity masks wouldn't disappear that soon in practice, but it's even harder to debug if they disappear at random.